# Checking unique values in array using LinkedHashSet in Java

Tags: java, arrays, linkedhashmap

I came across this code on [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-testing/problem), and I really confused myself by understanding this piece of code, which does **check uniqueness of the elements in the array using HashMap**.

Now to give you an insight, I know how to do this, and it is easy too. But this code is different and I really need to learn how and what it does actually.

```
int[] seq = new int[]{3,2,1,3};

Integer[] tmp = new Integer[seq.length];
for (int i = 0; i < seq.length; ++i) {
  tmp[i] = Integer.valueOf(seq[i]);
}

/* THIS PIECE OF CODE, HOW THIS WORKS AND WHAT IT DOES???*/         
if (!((new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(tmp))).size() == seq.length)) {
    throw new AssertionError("not all values are unique");
}
```

All I could make out is it converts the arrays into the list of `tmp`

```
Arrays.asList(tmp)
```

**2.** Converts it to the LinkedHashSet

```
LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(tmp))
```

**3.** Then finds the size of the HashSet

```
(LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(tmp))).size()
```

**4.** Compares it to the length of the array seq.

```
(new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(tmp))).size() == seq.length)
```

And if the length is not equal to the array `seq`, **then how come the elements are unique?**

Comment: Because `Set` only accepts unique elements, that's the basic definition of `Set`. If you try to add duplicate elements, one of them will be rejected and won't be added to instance of `Set`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code creates a `LinkedHashSet` that contains all the elements of the original array (boxed from `int` to `Integer`).

Since a `LinkedHashSet` (like all `Set`s) contains no duplicate elements, the original array has no duplicates if and only if the size of the `Set` is equal to the length of the array.

If the array had any duplicates, the size of the `Set` would have been smaller than the array's length, since the duplicates would have been eliminated when the `LinkedHashSet` is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does the following:

1. Converts the `Integer[]` to a `List<Integer>`. So that a `Set` object can be easily constructed out of the `List<Integer>`. This is because the `LinkedHasSet` has a constructor which accepts another `Collection` type and constructs a set from it using its values.
2. Converts the `List<Integer>` to `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` and when that happens, if there were duplicate `Integer`s in the `List<Integer>` as lists can have duplicates, that would be eliminated in the resulting set.
3. Now in the final step the size of the `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` is calculated if the size is not equal to the `length` of the original array `seq` then it means some elements in the `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` was duplicate and were removed on conversion.

> QUESTION: And if the length is not equal to the array seq, then how
>   come the elements are unique?

That is because if the resulting `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` has fewer elements compared to the initial `Integer[]` then it would mean that  duplicate objects were eliminated. And if they are equal it would mean that no objects were eliminated and all of them were unique.

If you want to do the check in fewer lines of code you can do this using the `Streams` API:

```
int[] seq = new int[]{3,2,1,3};
System.out.println(String.format("Array has duplicates: %b", 
                   Arrays.stream(seq).distinct().count() != seq.length));
```

This would give you `Array has duplicates: true` as it has duplicates in the `seq` array.